# Is a lattice countable?

Tags: soft-question, integer-lattices

I am studying lattices in the sense of a group in the context of number theory/cryptography. I wanted to note this briefly because lattices are not all the same.

There is a definition that a lattice is defined as a *discrete subgroup* of $\mathbb{R}^n$. My question now relates to if $L$ is a lattice in $\mathbb{R}^n$, is $L$ countable? If $L$ is countable, how do you justify that?

I am thinking if there is an argument for countability where one considers the open ball. However, this is just a thought.

Comment: What is the definition of 'discrete subsgroup'? This should help you to show that all elements can be enumerated, hence a lattice is countable.

Comment: @quarague, discrete means there is a, say, $p > 0$ for which $||x-y|| \geq p$, where $x,y \in L$ are lattice points. That would mean that the distance of the points cannot be arbitrary, and so one could perform a counting?

Comment: In fact, there is a sphere around each point (of radius $p/2$) which has no other points. Now pick one "rational" point (a point with all co-ordinates rational) in that sphere. Those will be all distinct. Now it suffices to recall that the set $\mathbb Q^n$ is countable.

Comment: @Stinking Bishop, this is a nice argument and a good illustration of the discreteness property! I like that! So my thought was not wrong in the previous comment?

Comment: No, not at all. What I've done is bridge the gap between "the distance of the points cannot be arbitrary" and "so one could perform a counting". (Which IMHO is a slightly bigger gap than it looks at the first sight.)

Comment: @StinkingBishop While I agree with the intention of what you want to show, I do not see how choosing a "rational" point in that sphere and countability of $\mathbb Q^n$ would show that.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg By providing an injection $L\to\mathbb Q^n$.